# Connecting to SQL server 2008 R2 remotely using VPN modems

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, remote-access, vpn

I am in the process of accessing a remote instance SQL server using VPN modems. The modems are in the same VPN network. I can ping each of the modems from the remote machines. I have already set the alias of the sql server instances to the ip address of the respective machines which I am using (the ip addresses) to connect to the remote machines. The problem is i am getting the error "A network related or instance specific error has occurred..." . What is it that may be causing this? Thanks.

Comment: Can you ping the target SQL Server from your client?

Comment: Yes I can. The target can also ping me back @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: Check if you have enabled named pipes on your sql server instance. use sql server configuration manager to do this

Comment: The named pipes are enabled. It is only the VIA which is not enabled. Could this be the issue? @Yugz

Comment: If Named pipes are enabled then that should eb fine.

Comment: Then i suspect you are possibly blocked off by your firewall. Speak to your network admin to allow access to port 1433.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When setting the alias of the sql server instances with the cliconfg command I did set it to the ip address of the local machine's modem. I have now changed it to the target machine (remote) ip address and I am now able to connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

From the object explorer open a new connect window scroll down the SERVER name values select the browse for more option then after select the Network Servers and choose the server to which you want to connect use SQL server authentication mode to connect to remote server

Comment: the ip address of the modems should work the same way as looking for the network machines. This way works too but it was not the cause of the problem. The way I set the alias could be the problem. @guarav tiwari